# Find a specific row in a excel range with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find rows on a sheet that meet given criteria(s).
I saw several times that authors perform this by filtering based on the search criteria but I don't like this method, so I am using something like this.

```
Sub fi()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = 100
    Dim myRow As Long
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 1) = "value1" And Cells(i, 3) = "value2" And Cells(i, 4) = "value3" Then
            i = myRow
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Does any of you have some good practice to do it on more efficient way? 
These are a kind of orders with 10 cells by row, but I can find what I need based on three of them. It is s typical sql select statement, but here I cannot use sql.
thanks

Comment: You could use ADODB for it

Comment: You could start by changing to `myRow = i`. Resetting your increment counter to zero when you find a match probably means that runs forver if a single match is found.

Comment: Use [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel).  Find _value1_ in column A and then check the offset from the returned cell references to see if _value2_ and _value3_ are also present.  It's very fast and plenty of examples on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (necessary comments in code):

```
Sub fi()
    Dim lastRow As Long, foundRange As Range
    'this will find last row for you, don't need to hard-code it
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'I used nested ifs, as it will boost the performance
    'it will stop checking next conditions if preceding condition fail
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 1) = "value1" Then
        If Cells(i, 3) = "value2" Then
        If Cells(i, 4) = "value3" Then
            'add columns A through J to foundRange
            If foundRange Is Nothing Then
                Set foundRange = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 10))
            Else
                Set foundRange = Union(foundRange, Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 10)))
            End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
    Next i
    foundRange.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I will try it.